# How  to view my database table and inserted values in cmd. after creating table in android

Tags: java, android, database, cmd

please help me with the command to view Sqlite tables and its contents.

```
    mydb = DbActivity.this.openOrCreateDatabase("asd", MODE_APPEND, null);
    mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hai(name varchar,password varchar)");
    mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO hai VALUES('"+ a + "','" + b + "')");
```

Comment: I reached upto D:\Software\Language Related\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform tools

Answer (score 0):

Open a database using the sqlite tool:

```
C:\> adb shell 
# sqlite3 /data/data/com.org.sample/databases/history.db

SQLite version 3.5.9
Enter ".help" for instructions

sqlite> .tables
android_metadata  suggestions

sqlite> .schema suggestions
CREATE TABLE suggestions (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,display1 TEXT UNIQUE ON CONFLICT REPLACE,display2 TEXT,query TEXT,date LONG);

sqlite> select * from suggestions;
2|randy pausch last lecture|Results for "randy pausch last lecture"|randy pausch last lecture|1264159994987
```

Answer (score 0):

**If** you use emulator or **if** your device is rooted:

1) At first I recommend you this plug-in for eclipse: http://coderzheaven.com/2011/04/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/

you can browse your database in it

2) second way in cmd:

```
adb -s emulator-5554 shell
sqlite3 /data/data/your-app-folder/databases/database-name.db
select * from myTable
```

**If** your device is not rooted you can not do anything.